# Why Is My Makefile Having Trouble Finding OpenSSL on Mac?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am working on a cryptography project and everything seemed to be running smoothly. Our professor provided us with the skeleton (makefile included). Now however I get this error:

```
gcc  -O2 -Wall -c ske.c -o ske.o
In file included from ske.c:1:
./ske.h:4:10: fatal error: 'openssl/aes.h' file not found
#include <openssl/aes.h>
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [ske.o] Error 1
```

I've tried adding

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

to the makefile and have installed and uninstalled openssl. Furthermore, the error is not limited to the aes.h header file, I've seen sha.h and a couple of others. Here is my makefile:

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
HEADERS := $(wildcard *.h)
TARGETS := kem-enc
TSOURCE := $(wildcard tests/*.c)
TESTS   := $(TSOURCE:.c=)

COMMON   := -O2 -Wall
CFLAGS   := $(CFLAGS) $(COMMON)
CC       := gcc
LDADD    := -lcrypto -lssl -lgmp
LD       := $(CC)
LDFLAGS  := -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
DEFS     :=

ifeq ($(shell uname),Linux)
DEFS += -DLINUX
endif

IMPL := ske.o rsa.o kem-enc.o
ifdef skel
IMPL := $(IMPL:.o=-skel.o)
endif

all : $(TARGETS)
.PHONY : all

# {{{ for debugging
debug : CFLAGS += -g -DDEBUG=1
debug : $(TARGETS) $(TESTS)
.PHONY : debug
# }}}

$(OBJECTS) : %.o : %.c $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(TARGETS) : $(IMPL) prf.o
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDADD)

tests : $(TESTS)
.PHONY : tests

$(TESTS) : % : %.o $(filter-out kem-enc.o,$(IMPL)) prf.o
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDADD)

.PHONY : clean
clean :
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(TARGETS) $(TESTS) $(TSOURCE:.c=.o)
```

I am running Mac OS Mojave. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this??

Comment: My openssl is included from /usr/local/include/openssl.  Also, you should edit CFLAGS rather than CPPFLAGS

Comment: got it!! yeah I'm assuming CPP is c++ and Im compiling c code so it's not using that to find openssl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working. Here's what I did.

1. Deleted `-lopenssl` flag from `LDADD`.
2. Added `-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include` to `CFlAGS` after the text that was already there.

Now it works!!